# How to sync Synology to my AD Server?

Tags: nas, active-directory, synology

I'm covering for our normal IT person so I need the answer to be explained in a way that doesn't assume I know much as I don't and am still learning/taking notes.

Right now no one can access our NAS with this error appearing -
[image]

I looked up this error with Synology which is the our NAS Software and I found this thread https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/133880 where it seems the issue is a time sync issue between our AD and Synology.

I see this error in the my Domain/LDAP on my Synology
[image]

and my domain status is as follows -
[image]

How can I resolve the time sync issue between Synology and my AD?  Is this something I can do from Synology?  I do have the login credentials for our admin.microsoft account as well if that's where I would need to fix things.  I have already restarted Synology once but that did not fix anything.

Thank you for any help.

Edit:  Some extra details.  Some of my coworkers are able to get on no problem, and others are not.  I tried some solutions on my end.  I changed my Interactive Logon: How many logons to cache to 0, signed out and signed in, and that worked for me, but not a coworker.

Answer (score 0):

Our IT guy was able to remote in and save the day.  All it took was opening up the Domain/LDAP screen on Synology from Control Panel

Uncheck `Join domain`, click Apply, then check `Join Domain` and click apply again.  Will require your admin password.  This fixed it for us.